# How to limit the number of dropdown results in v-autocomplete?

Tags: vue.js, v-autocomplete

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k81wa.png) I receive 100-200 results from the axios api. I want to show only first 10 from it. Is there any way I can do that. I cannot do that from api since I also want to show the count of total items returning from axios.

Edit: I have a show all button which shows the list of all the item in new pop up. Due to this I want the exact count of total items that are returning but only want to display top 10 results from it.

Comment: modify the response so that you take only top 10 records from it

Comment: Try `<v-autocomplete :items="items.slice(0,10)"> ...`

Comment: @Braks But this way I won't be able to show the exact count of items present, it will always be less than equal to 10.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use menu-props and adjust the height

```
<v-autocomplete  :menu-props='{ nudgeTop: 110,maxHeight: 125}'></v-autocomplete>
```